# object pdf type is not render in mozilla and chrome

Tags: jsf, pdf, primefaces

Im doing a document searching system, that shows a list of pdf like response, I´m working with primefaces 5

this is my code

```
<h:outputLink value="file/#{document.pdfPath}" target="_blank" >view document</h:outputLink>
                <div id="pdf2">
                <object data='file/#{document.pdfPath}' 
                        type='application/pdf' 
                        width='700px' 
                        height='400px'>


                <p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
                No worries, just <a href='file/#{document.pdfPath}'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>


                </object>


                        <div id="pdf">
                            <object data="http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/hello.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="450" height="375"></object>
                        </div>
```

But this is the problem in eclipse and IE browser runs perfect,but in chorme and mozilla only show the pdf that doesn´t come from a managed bean.
it is what I´m watching

With chrome
[image: chrome]

With mozilla
[image: Mozilla]

and finally Internet explorer (works perfect here)
[image: IE]

Comment: What's `/file`? Is it a public webapp folder with all static files? Or is it a servlet returning some dynamic content? What exactly is the full URL? Does it have the `.pdf` extension? I'm also confused by the phrasing "come from a managed bean". The code doesn't seem to indicate that the PDF is coming from a managed bean. You're merely printing the PDF path. I'm also confused by `[primefaces]` tag as that suggested that you were using its `<p:media>` for PDF files before I started reading the question.

Comment: Ok BalusC thanks for your answer.
First the file is a path where a servlet returns dinamyc content hte complete url contains the .pdf, see in the IE screenshot the file is displayed. And about the manage bean i miss to type about that the code is in a list, this is the complete code
http://pastie.org/9492531

Comment: Okay. That servlet, does it properly set the response content type?

Comment: Yes, have a rigth behavior, actually in chrome when I inspect the code, and y make click in the  link, I can download the file.

Comment: Okay, can you show the response headers the browser actually retrieves? Press F12 in Chrome, check *Network*, open the request on PDF, scroll to bottom and check "Response headers".

Comment: this is what I get when I search for the item named contratotest.pdf
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1419x445q90/537/JG6Es1.jpg,
the mistery is why works in IE and eclipse debuger and doesn´t in the others ones when i make the call from the bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, from your response headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="contratotest.pdf"
```

Your `/file` servlet is serving the PDF as an `attachment`. This is intented for the "Save As" dialogue thing. If you intend to display the content inline in the web page instead of as an attachment of the web page, then you need to set it to `inline`.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
```

Or just remove it entirely. It's the default already. You may only need to add an extra parameter to the fallback link to force `attachment` anyway when clicked.

Comment: Thanks man,  but where I have to do that, im pretty new in jsf.

Comment: Uh, just in the code of `/file` servlet. There where it currently sets the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`. You said that you've a servlet for that?

Comment: Man you are a master, i just comentted the line and works perfect.
Really thankyou SO MUCH